# How to control an interactive ssh session with Python's subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh

I'm trying to control an *interactive* ssh session from python - so not running `ssh user@host command` (which there are loads of answers for) but `ssh user@host` then writing to/reading from that ssh session from Python.

What I've tried always starts with:

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys

ssh_cmd = ["ssh", "-tt", "whoever@myhost"]
proc = sp.Popen(ssh_cmd, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
while True:
    stdin = raw_input('enter command: ')
    proc.stdin.write(b'%s\n' % stdin)
```

the problem is how to read proc.stdout:

- `proc.stdout.readlines()` doesn't work as it never returns EOF, so it blocks
- `proc.stdout.readline()` works if there is one line of data ready, but `proc.stdout` doesn't return '' when empty so there's no way to read through it, and if there's no data it blocks
- `select` and `poll` always say that `proc.stdout` is "ready" for reading regardless of whether or not `proc.stdout.readline()` will actually work.

Any suggestions?

Edit: code here is python2.7 but solutions for python3 would be fine too.
Edit: using `proc.communicate()` isn't an option here as that waits for the process to finish, and I want to keep reading/writing to it.

Comment: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm well Marcin Orlowski's suggestion is certainly low-effort although I don't feel I've learnt what was the problem with the original!

```
from paramiko.client import SSHClient

client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect("myhost", username="whoever")
while True:
    cmd = raw_input('enter command: ')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
    print ''.join(stdout.readlines())
```

Comment: This option is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

To answer code "What's wrong with the original?", I would say there could be a couple of things:

1. If you are running Python 3, then to convert the string returned by `raw_input` to bytes, you need to encode it with: `stdin.encode()`.
   The will use the system default encoding, which is usually `UTF-8`. The expression you used, `b'%s\n' % stdin`, where `stdin` is a `str`, should throw an exception unless you are running Python 2, in which case there is no real difference between a `str` and a `byte`. The only method `raw_input` in Python 3 I know is from class `code.InteractiveConsole`. I don't see an import statement for that so this suggests you are running Python 2, so I am not sure why you were trying to do the conversion from a string to bytes to begin with.
2. **The real problem** is that you need to call `proc.communicate()`, which is needed to send the results of all the writes you did to`proc.stdin` to the actual process and to retrieve the output the process did to `stdout` and `stderr`. Until you do that, nothing happens. The bottom line is that `subprocess.Popen` is not meant to be used for an interactive dialog. It should be used for just sending some fixed input to a process, calling `communicate()` and then retrieving the resulting output.

**Demos Using `subprocess`**

```
import subprocess as sp
import time

ssh_cmd = ["grep", "age"]
proc = sp.Popen(ssh_cmd, stdin=sp.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(b'age1\n')
proc.stdin.write(b'age2\n')
proc.stdin.write(b'age3\n')
time.sleep(5) # nothing happens for these 5 seconds
proc.communicate() # now the output will start coming out


# second demo use pipes for output:
ssh_cmd = ["grep", "age"]
proc = sp.Popen(ssh_cmd, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(b'age1\n')
proc.stdin.write(b'age2\n')
proc.stdin.write(b'age3\n')
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate() # retrieve outputs form the process
#print(stdout.decode()) # convert from bytes to string for Python 3
print stdout # Python 2
```

Prints (after 5 seconds):

```
age1
age2
age3
age1
age2
age3
```

Comment: 1. This was using python 2.7, sorry should have flagged that.
2. I don't want to call `proc.communicate()` because that waits for the process to terminate - I want to keep sending stdin and receiving stdout from the process.

Comment: And my whole point is that until you call `proc.communicate()` nothing will be sent to your process and therefore that is why your using `Popen` for an interactive session is doomed to failure. You said (and I quote verbatim), "I don't feel I've learnt what was the problem with the original!" so I was just trying to provide an answer to that with a demonstration.

Comment: But `proc.stdin.write()` demonstrably *does* send to the process without having to call `proc.communicate()`, as if the process's stdout is multiline then `proc.stdout.readline()` will show the first line of output. Its just that calling that repeatedly apparently doesn't have the normal file semantics. Am I misunderstanding you here??

Comment: No. My first demo is doing a `grep age` command to return lines that contain `age` anywhere within. It then immediately writes 3 lines of input to grep but then waits 5 seconds before calling `proc.communicate()`. If these three lines were going immediately to `grep` I would expect to see the output, which is not being piped, displayed right away. But in fact it is not output until the 5 seconds have elapsed and I finally call `proc.communicate()`. Why not try running the demo if you have a `grep` command?

Comment: From the Python manual concerning the `communicate` method: **Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.** This is not interactive. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=communicate#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: I think you've misunderstood your demo and the docs TBH - & I **know** `proc.communicate()` is not interactive, hence why I'm not using it. If you don't explicitly read from stdout, then of course you don't see output until you call `proc.communicate()`. It doesn't mean the process hasn't received any writes to its stdin (although that may depend on buffering, so calling `flush` after a write would be recommended here, & I imagine `.communicate()` does that as a side-effect). The wording "send data to stdin" for `communicate()` refers to it's `input` parameter, not to direct writes to stdin.

Comment: It's true that a call to `sys.stdin.flush()` would start the output coming in the first demo but only because pipes are not being used for output, i.e. grep is writing directly to the terminal. But in the second demo, where the output is being output to a pipe, the only way to get it is through the `communicate` method, which then waits until the process ends, so it is non-interactive. But you then say, "I know proc.communicate() is not interactive, hence why I'm not using it."  (continued)

Comment: But you *did* attempt to use Popen with a pipes for output which requires proc.communicate, it was not working, you came up with an alternate solution, but still did not understand why your original Popen with pipes did not work for an interactive session. I was just trying to explain why over and over. See my point no 2 of my answer: "The real problem is that you need to call proc.communicate(), which is needed to send the results of all the writes you did to proc.stdin to the actual process **and to retrieve the output the process did to stdout and stderr.**" Let's put this to rest.